# scope of "new", has no "free" counter part

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I notice there is no `free` keyword in Java, which leads to me ask why.
When I create a new object or array, what is the scope of that variable?

I am familiar with C++ and C.

Comment: Java has got an automatic garbage collection.

Comment: But you cant know when it is freed. So, it has a scope in **time** too!

Comment: You are confusing objects with variables. And no, this is nothing Java specific, C and C++ have the same distinction and it's even more important.

Comment: Scope pertains to the name;  new/free pertains to memory management which is not part of scope.

Comment: @delnan: except that in C++ when you have non-pointer, non-reference variables then scope == object lifetime.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Yes, and while those can take you a long way in C++ with RAII, I would not call anyone not aware of the distinction a C++ programmer, and a C programmer can't even write the most trivial programs correctly (except of course by accident).

Answer (score 4):

How long an Object lives has little to do with scope of a local variable in Java. e.g.

```
File f = new File("a");
f = new File("b"); 
// variable f is still in scope but the first object can be cleaned up.
```

or

```
private final List<File> files = ...


{
    File f = new File("a");
    files.add(f);
} // f is out of scope but the object lives on in "files".
```

Answer (score 3):

1. variables don't hold objects in Java, they hold primitive values or object *references* (important distinction: just because your variable goes out of scope, doesn't mean that the object can be garbage-collected, it might still be reachable via some other reference )
2. the scope of *variables* is very similar to C/C++

   - block or method (for local variables)
   - object (for non-static fields) or
   - class (for static fields)
3. *objects* get garbage collected when they are not longer reachable (not immediately, but eventually).

Comment: Objects can and should be collected regardless of how many references to them exist. Only **reachability** matters.

Answer (score 0):

Scope depends on where you created the new variable (or) object.

If you created as Instance variable/object, it's scope is for that instance.

If you created as class variable/object (static), it's scope is classloader.

If you created as local variable/object (static), it's scope is for that method.

If an object is not reachable then it is eligible for GC (irrespective of scope).

Answer (score 0):

Variable has standard scope: method or block (unless it is an instance variable). Variables (I mean primitives or references) are kept on **stack** while objects and arrays (even array of primitives) is always kept on **heap**.

Object (array is an object too) can of course be passed out from a variable scope and leave there. Object lives as long as it is reachable (there is a way to get to it through a reference graph). It has nothing to do with scope.

On the other hand variable lives in a scope **always**. There is no way to pass it anywhere and modify. References are always passed to methods and returned as a copy.

Comment: Here too: Whether there are references to an object does not matter to the GC; what matters is whether an object is reachable.

Comment: If you really want to be precise you should mention weak, soft and phantom references in Java... this is out of scope of the question. Of course being richable is the correct terminology.

Comment: Those distinctions could (and probably should) be ignored for a beginner question. But "has references" instead of "is reachable" is misleading even for beginners if they are bright enough to think of cycles (take a look around, there are many questions whether GCs can handle those). I think we should explain that correctly right from the bat to prevent misconceptions.